# javascript asynchronous task handling

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, rabbitmq

I am new to Node development.
I having trouble understanding the asynchronous nature of JS and Node. I am building a microservices backend web server, running Express in the gateway service which translated REST requests to series of messages published using a RabbitMQ asynchronous messaging (amqplib) module, which in turn, other services can subscribe to, process the request and then respond.

My service which processes the asynchronous request from the gateway looks like this:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://172.17.0.2', function(err, conn) {
  console.log("connection created");
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    console.log("channel created");
    var exchange = 'main';

    ch.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {durable: true});

    ch.assertQueue('', {exclusive: true}, function(err, q) {
      console.log(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C');

      ch.bindQueue(q.queue, exchange, "VENUE_TOPIC.PENDING_STATUS.*.*");

      ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg) { 
        console.log(" [x] %s:'%s'", msg.fields.routingKey, msg.content.toString());
        var pending_event = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString())
        console.log(pending_event.payload.id == 2)
        console.log(pending_event.payload.id)
        if (pending_event.payload.id == 1) { 
          var venue = getVenueByID(pending_event.payload.id);
          const approved_event = new Event("VENUE_TOPIC", "APPROVED_STATUS", false, "READ_METHOD", {"venue":venue});
          var key = approved_event.getMetaAsTopics();

          var msg = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(approved_event.getEventAsJSON()));

          ch.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {durable: true});
          ch.publish(exchange, key, msg, {persistent: true});
          console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);        
        } else if (pending_event.payload.id == 2) {
          sleep(10000); //this function checks the OS's clock to count time in ms
          var venue = getVenueByID(pending_event.payload.id);
          const approved_event = new Event("VENUE_TOPIC", "APPROVED_STATUS", false, "READ_METHOD", {"venue":venue}); 
          var key = approved_event.getMetaAsTopics();

          var msg = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(approved_event.getEventAsJSON()));

          ch.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {durable: true});
          ch.publish(exchange, key, msg, {persistent: true});
          console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
        }
      }, {noAck: true});
    });
  });
});
```

Let's say I have 2 requests, one which takes long to complete and another which is shorter. The longer request comes in before the shorter one.
In my example the long process is ID === 2 and the short process is ID === 1.

Now, if I send a request where ID is 2 and then immediately send a request where ID is 1, I have to wait 10 seconds for the first to complete, and then the other completes.

I cannot understand if it is possible to process both requests concurrently, without having the long process block the short process until it completes.

Comment: Read about promises (example [here](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)) - it's the modern way of handling asynchronous parts of code, in my (and I'm not the only one  :)) opinion more transparent than callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment since I don't have enough SO reputation, but I'll try to provide as much insight as possible.

Assuming `sleep` is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) npm package this is expected behavior, so called `blocking` behavior. If you're planning to make non-blocking calls (like web requests) inside your consume function you will be fine and node will be able to consume further messages when it is processing. However if you need to do blocking/cpu heavy lifting and still be able to process incoming messages you will need to offload this work to some worker.

Try this code instead, it will "sleep" without blocking:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    var venue = getVenueByID(pending_event.payload.id);
    const approved_event = new Event("VENUE_TOPIC", "APPROVED_STATUS", false, "READ_METHOD", {
        "venue": venue
    });
    var key = approved_event.getMetaAsTopics();

    var msg = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(approved_event.getEventAsJSON()));

    ch.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {
        durable: true
    });
    ch.publish(exchange, key, msg, {
        persistent: true
    });
    console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
}, 10000);
```